# MS SQL Server - update row value to next row with row id

Tags: locking

I have a table like below:

```
Newid1       a   b   c
   1       null  40  50
   2       null  45  55
   3       null  46  56
   4       null  47  57
   5       null  48  58
```

Now I want to update value in a column by updating C column value into it (For example: 50 to the second row, 55 to the third row, 56 to the fourth row ...). How can I do this with WHILE command. 
Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done in one set based operation
Using a WHILE risks invoking the "[Halloween problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem)" as you update rows over and over.

It's easier with SQL Server 2012 using LAG

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Newid1 int
    , a int  NULL
    , b int
    , c int
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, NULL, 40, 50)
        ,(2, NULL, 45, 55) ,(3, NULL, 46, 56)
        ,(4, NULL, 47, 57) ,(5, NULL, 48, 58);

-- SQL Server 2012
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT a, LAG(c) OVER (ORDER BY Newid1) AS nextC
    FROM @t
)
UPDATE t SET a = nextC;

SELECT * FROm @t;
```

But for SQL Server 2005+

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Newid1 int
    , a int  NULL
    , b int
    , c int
);

-- SQL Server 2005+
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT Newid1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Newid1) +1 AS nextID, a, c
    FROM @t
)
UPDATE t1
SET a = t2.c
FROM
   t AS t1
   JOIN
   t AS t2 ON t1.Newid1 = t2.nextID;

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no `WHILE`, just shift on 1 by ROW_NUMBER if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Newid1 int
    , a int  NULL
    , b int
    , c int
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, NULL, 40, 50)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, NULL, 45, 55)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(3, NULL, 46, 56)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(4, NULL, 47, 57)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(5, NULL, 48, 58)


UPDATE t
   SET a = c.c
FROM @t t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
     a.NewId1
     ,b.c
    FROM ( SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY Newid1) + 1, * FROM @t) b    
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY Newid1), * FROM @t) a
            ON a.Id = b.Id
) c
ON c.NewId1 = t.NewId1

SELECT  * FROM @t
```

Comment: Sorry, but what if I want to calculate the C column and update it to the a column of next row. I mean the value in C column is a dynamic value! You're very kind to help me with this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Teddy NGUYEN no problem, but it should be optimized with CTE clause to improve performance (double select on @t: row_number and row_number + 1)

Comment: Dear Garik, thank you so much for this support. BTW, if you don't mind, can you give me some more ways to contact you (email,IM...), because I'm a newbie of SQL, I must have had more questions that need your help. Terribly sorry if my request cause inconvenience to you! :) Best regards!

Comment: @Teddy NGUYEN just ask questions on this site. It does not depend knew you something before, any way it is a good chance to learn more.

Comment: what if I have the value of the A column at the first row (rowid =1) only and I want to use that value for calculating those next row. In my case, I updated the first row at column A with a static value 20. After that, I use this value for calculating: a(20) + b - c (20+40-50=10). The 10 value will be updated to the second row and calculate the result for the third row: (10 + 45 - 55 = 0), the 0 value will be updated to the third row at column A, and continue calculating (0 + 46 - 56 = -10), and more... Once again, thanks a lot! :-)